# Is there a code template/design pattern I can use when reacting to mouse clicks or button presses?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

One of the problems that I constantly see with Winforms applications is that the GUI thread is stuck while a long-running task is running or just plain stops refreshing (yes, I know - needs threading).

Is there a code template/design pattern I can use when reacting to mouse clicks or button presses? Should there be a processing thread always running in the GUI app?

Basically, how do I write a great Winforms Application that is easy to maintain and doesn't have any quirky refresh bugs?

Comment: Your question is too generic, you need to provide specific problem details. Flagged as subjective.

Comment: don't get discouraged by down votes you can get alot of good help here - maybe try phrasing a question like "here's what i did, here's what happened, why?"

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar - sometimes there is no specific problem. Sometimes people just look for suggestions to better themselves or learn something new.

Comment: I think SO is not that forum, you should check programmers forum which is more suitable for such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: If you look at the new Async CTP you'll see that BackgroundWorker is becoming obsolete for small tasks that don't need a dedicated thread.

Comment: @Jeremy: Haven't looked at it yet... but since it's a CTP it's probably not completely usable I guess, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad Its more than usable. Its been out for nearly a year and has been recently revised. It will be included in C#5.

Comment: @Jeremy: But doesn't it have to be installed on the target machine? It's much less likely for the user to have it installed.
@Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: @Mehrdad I upvoted to counter-balance the downvote. As far as I can see its just a matter of including the dll's in the folder of your project.

Comment: @Jeremy: Lol, thanks. :D And oh, I didn't know it was redistributable; in that case then it would probably be a great solution!

Comment: @Mehrdad Check out videos on TechEd like http://www.msteched.com/2010/Europe/DEV301

Comment: @Jeremy: Sure, I'll watch them when I get the chance, thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy: Code doesn't suddenly go bad just because someone writes something to replace it.  `BackgroundWorker` is still a perfectly sensible way to keep a Winforms UI responsive.  +1

Comment: @Robert Harvey I did not say it suddenly went bad. But if you have to create 15 threads to complete a task there are issues with how you implement Threads/BackgroundWorker. I am merely suggesting another paradigm. "With more threads comes great responsibility".

Comment: @Jeremy: Well, who says you need 15 threads?  `BackgroundWorker` only requires one.  If you really need that many threads, there's always `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Will definitely try using BackgroundWorker. How do you know if something is taking too long? what is too long? It seems to me that any time you have a button click you should have BackgroundWorker handle it just so you never run the risk of hanging your GUI. Is it a good idea to use BackgroundWorker while handling EVERY button click? (theoretically, if you don't use BackgroundWorker then your GUI is hanging (even for a miniscule amount of time)

Comment: @Denis: Use `BackgroundWorker` only for long-running tasks. You get to decide what "long running" means (ten seconds or more?), but the goal is to keep the UI reasonably responsive while the background task is running. Generally speaking, you will only need to handle one long-running task, and most forms will not need a `BackgroundWorker` at all. Using a `BackgroundWorker` allows you to pass progress information back to the UI. See here for a good example of how to use BackgroundWorker properly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question is you are looking for a Solid Respectable Framework for GUI on .net then I say Look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) or Caliburn.

Comment: +1 (and added link). You beat me to it!

Comment: +1 for Prism Link! Thank you both!

Comment: Prism appears to be WPF and Silverlight, not Winforms.

Comment: Hmm, Three +1's in comments, but only one upvote, and one downvote.

Comment: Yes, Both of them are only for WPF at the this time.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the new Async CTP here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360

And tutorial here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/10/28/visual-studio-async-ctp-for-the-rest-of-ushellip.aspx

Regardless of the method to deliver the UI the new Async CTP provides simple solutions to GUI threading and responsiveness.

Follow n-tier development practices, use unit testing and coded UI testing(MSTest for instance), and profile your application to find bottlenecks and memory issues.

Comment: This is awesome! Never knew about CTP. I wonder when this officially gets released.

Comment: It will be released with C#5. And yes it is amazingly awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening VS2010 and creating a new C# Winforms app.  Run it, it should be fine.

Use the forms designer to add controls and event handlers.

If the event handler does something that is slow, add a background worker component, and put the slow code in the event handler it provides for a separate thread.

The UI thread will be responsive as long as you don't slow it down with code in an event handler.

My best advice is for you to believe that writing responsive winforms apps is not only possible, but really pretty easy with modern development tools.  If you followed the above and have a specific wierdness then post the specific thing as a question, and you'll probably get help.

Also, you don't have to get fancy for simple apps - I just transitioned to the MVP pattern after more than 6 months of iterations on a fairly advanced LOB app project.  I'm looking at MVVM now, but won't start really using it until I see the advantage.